# EJB application hosting

Tags: java, hosting, ejb

I am studying ejb and developing an application. I want to host and see how it works. I searched everywhere ejb hostings:cloud,vps hosting. But their hosting cost is very expensive for me. Now I am thinking of a home server. but the problem is if I run it, the security risk will be there as I am willing to promote my application and invite people to use my application.I am not an expert in server security.Any one tell me how I can host my ejb application or how to establish my home server(any useful link or tutorial).
I think if I run start a home server I will have to configure security in the application server+container.(Let's forget the disadvantages of machine wast ages and power consumption as because if my home server succeeds I will continue it for future)

Answer (score 1):

If your application will run on a tomcat server (which is not a full EJB server) you may have a look at
[Amazons Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/en/elasticbeanstalk/).

There you can get all the nice features from amazon like:

- managed application server
- load balancing
- monitoring
- database & data store
- nice management and development tools
- much much more

And if you're a new AWS-User you can get all these for a low traffic application one year for free.